# Envlab and datatool: Error: missing number

Tags: datatool, envlab

Running the following through LaTeX gives me a "Missing number" error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[c5envelope,noprintreturnaddress,capaddress]{envlab}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\makelabels
\begin{document}
\startlabels
\DTLloaddb{recipients}{recipients.csv}
\DTLforeach*{recipients}{\firstname=Vorname,%
 \surname=Nachname,%
 \address1=Adresszeile1,%
 \address2=Adresszeile2,%
 \city=Ort,%
 \postcode=PLZ}{%
\mlabel{Dummy}{%
 \firstname \surname\\
 \address1\\
 \address2\\
 \city \postcode}}
\end{document}
```

This is my recipients.csv file:

```
Vorname,Nachname,Adresszeile1,Adresszeile2,PLZ,Ort
Wolfang,Ingeborg,Im Wiengert,Baumgartnerstrasse 11,8800,Biel
```

Do yo see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use `\address1` and `\address2` as macros? Try changing them to `\addressone` and `\addresstwo` to see if that fixes things. In general, you can't use numbers in macro names.

Comment: @quagmire This works for me. Have you considered upgrading your packages?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen No, it doesn't work. Two lines are printed the same.

Comment: @egreg OK. Now I understand what was meant with "it doesn't work". I thought the poster got a runtime error:-)

Answer (score 5):

You are defining twice the `\address` macro and *not* macros `\address1` and `\address2`. Only letters can appear in macro names

```
\DTLforeach*{recipients}{\firstname=Vorname,%
 \surname=Nachname,%
 \addressA=Adresszeile1,%
 \addressB=Adresszeile2,%
 \city=Ort,%
 \postcode=PLZ}{%
\mlabel{Dummy}{%
 \firstname \surname\\
 \addressA\\
 \addressB\\
 \city \postcode}}
```